# Key/Pair value retrieval is stuck on "activity running" after clicking save button

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a table of courses & course descriptions in a SQL database. For example

**Course Code**          --------------------     **Course Name**

Engineering101  ......................Basics of physics

Math101 .................................Basics of calculus

........... etc

I want to retrieve the value of **Course Name** lets say "Basics of Physics" description after typing **Course Code** Engineering101 into an edit text field.

My file breaks here:

```
public void saveData(View view) {
        EditText courseCodeName, courseCodeNumber;
        courseCodeName = findViewById(R.id.course_code);
        courseCodeNumber=findViewById(R.id.course_number);
        //get course name based off of coursenumber. make sure course name field blank
        if(courseCodeName.toString()=="" |courseCodeNumber.toString()!=""){
            // get codename and course name columns
            Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT _id, course_name1, course_code1 FROM contacts WHERE course_code1 like '"+courseCodeNumber+"'",
                    null);
            if(c!=null){
                if(c.moveToFirst()){
                    do{
                        final String[] courseName=c.getColumnNames();// <---BREAKS HERE
                        String m = courseName[0];
                        //String course_name=c.getString(c.getColumnNames(dBContract.MenuEntry.COLUMN_CODE));
                        Log.v("Set Correctly?", m);

                    }while(c.moveToNext());
                }
            }
```

What is causing this to happen? It just says "Activity Running" and that's it.

Thanks.

Comment: You can use `String m = c.getString(0));` directly id you want to retrieve any column's value from Cursor by position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By reading the comment above the `if (...)`

```
//get course name based off of coursenumber. make sure course name field blank
```

I think that it should be:

```
if(courseCodeName.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty() && !courseCodeNumber.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty())
```

Then use a safe way to query the table to avoid sql injection by using placeholders:

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT course_name1 FROM contacts WHERE course_code1 = ?", new String[] {courseCodeNumber});
```

I changed the statement to return only `course_name1` because you are not interested in any other columns and also changed `like` to `=`.
Then, I don't know if you really need a loop. Do you expect more than 1 rows returned?
I don't thing so because I suppose `course_code1` is unique (or not?). 
So do this:

```
if(c.moveToFirst()){
    String course_name = c.getString(0);
    ..................................
}
```